# Dotnet Core 3.1 (REST) Api Memory Leaks Problem with the GC or something else that causes a hell of a Memory load

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

i have a Problem with the GC or someting else that causes a memory leak, i have read a lot of Articles about it and heard of similar problems, but the couldn`t helped me to find the solution.

**The Problem**: is that the Memory is increasing every Request and doesn't get freed on completion.

[shows the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK84J.png)

Comment: It's normal that a process uses memory if it is available. This is not necessarily a symptom of a memory leak.

Comment: Have you actually used a memory profiler to check if there is a leak? Just seeing the process memory graph increase does not actually say anything at all. With a proper profiler you can see how much memory is actually needed, and it also makes it fairly easy to find common mistakes, like not unregistering event-handlers.

Comment: yes i have used a memory profiler and i have snapshotted it to see what generate that amount of unused memory